# How can I create a Yahoo account using my existing email address?

Tags: account-management, yahoo

Both Microsoft and Google allow you to create an account on their sites using your own email address instead of `@live.com` or `@gmail.com`. When you try to create a Yahoo account it allows you to choose between an `@yahoo.com`, `@ymail.com`, or `@rocketmail.com` email address.

Is there a way to use your existing email address instead of one of these?

Comment: +1 from me. I wanted to sign up to a yahoogroup earlier, and was presented with a page to create a yahoo email address. It wasn't all that important so I just gave up.

Comment: I believe this looks to be possible now via this link https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?specId=usernamereg . 

Link was obtained via by going to https://login.yahoo.com/ , clicking the "Create an account" button, then clicking "I want to use my current email address". 

Their help page as seems to confirm it is possible  https://help.yahoo.com/kb/sln2056.html : "Create a new account or use an existing email address from any email provider; you'll just need to provide a password, date of birth, and a mobile number."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do the equivalent on Yahoo, but there is a way to make it so you don't get mail to your Yahoo Email address.

This is what I did:

1. Create the Yahoo Account using one of their domains (e.g. `@yahoo.com`).
2. During the account creation, set your **Alternate Email** account to your real email address. (Alternatively, go to your account information after creating an account and add another email address.)
3. After the account is created, go to the **Account Info** page.
4. Next to **Email**, press **Change**.
5. Make sure you verified your real email address.
6. Make your real email address your primary address by checking the box next to it.

The primary email is defined as:

> This email address will be used as the
>   primary way Yahoo! communicates with
>   you.

This means that as long as you don't sign up to any services using your Yahoo email address, you should only be getting email to your real email address and never have to check the new Yahoo email address you just created. Although it may expire due to inactivity....

Answer (score 2):

yahoo doesn't allow you to do this.

Gmail for example allows you to use the Gmail interface to use your existing e-mail setup, accessing it via POP or IMAP.  Yahoo doesn't have that offering.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking to use it as an email account but rather as a login to their different services.